# How to make RegionPlot3D automatically choose PlotRange?

Tags: plotting

I'm looking at the [winning one-liners of 2014](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/11/10/announcing-the-winners-of-the-2014-one-liner-competition/), this one inparticular:

```
s = WolframAlpha["bat ineqalty", "Result"]@2; RegionPlot3D[
 N[s[x, y] && s[x, z] && s[y, z]], {x, -14, 14}, {y, -8, 8}, {z, -8, 
  8}, PlotPoints -> 90]
```

It seems the x,y, and y intervals were chose by hand. I would like to know how I can make Mathematica choose the plot range automatically - any reasonable bounding box would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

I think the range of plotting could be determined by using `MaxValue` and `MinValue`:

```
s = WolframAlpha["bat ineqalty", "Result"]@2;
range0 = Outer[#1[{#2, s[x, y]}, {x, y}] &, {MaxValue, MinValue}, {x, y}];
range = Through[{Min, Max}@range0];
RegionPlot3D[s[x, y] && s[x, z] && s[y, z], {x, ##}, {y, ##}, {z, ##},
    PlotPoints -> 90, Mesh -> False] & @@ range
```

[image: regionplot3D of bat]

It should be noted that in version 10.1 the following code is available:

```
s = WolframAlpha["bat ineqalty", "Result"]@2;
range0=RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[s[x, y], {x, y}]];
range=MinMax[range0];
 RegionPlot3D[s[x, y] && s[x, z] && s[y, z], {x, ##}, {y, ##}, {z, ##},
        PlotPoints -> 90, Mesh -> False] & @@ range
```

Comment: In v10.1 you can use the function `MinMax` :) BTW, I noticed something interesting. In v8.0.4 `WolframAlpha["bat ineqalty", "Result"]` only returns an inequality, not a pure function!

Comment: @xzczd Thank you,xzcyr.

Comment: You're welcome, qsraaaa520.

Comment: @xzczd Could you upvote my question?I am wating for any answers.http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79572/some-bug-may-ocurr-while-doing-regionplot-with-v10-1

Comment: I've already upvoted it. BTW there is no definite relationship between upvotes and being answered.