# RegionPlot returning a number

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.3.0.0 or later**

---

I had updated my mathematica to version 10 few days ago. And I had been shocked by the following fact:

```
s = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];
RegionPlot[InverseFunction[s][x] <= y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]       
(* -1.13757 *)
```

Oh, my god! It is a number rather than a graph.

It seem like a bug about [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html), [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html) and [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) because I then try another code:

```
s = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];
RegionPlot3D[InverseFunction[s][x] <= y z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

It certainly get the graph!

I later tried to use version 9 with the first code:

```
s = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];
RegionPlot[InverseFunction[s][x] <= y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

a graph got as well.

Comment: Normally, [tag:bugs] is reserved for when the community believes something is a bug, and should not be applied without that input. However, I'll confirm it, and it's certainly odd.

Comment: I've reported it.

Comment: I do not know if it was urgent but in waiting for a solution is this usefull ?     Plot[{InverseFunction[s][x], x}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red, None}}}]

Comment: Still a problem under V11.0.0, though it now returns `Show[-1.13757, DisplayFunction -> Identity]`

Comment: However, this works `RegionPlot[InverseFunction[Sin][x] <= y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`...

Comment: Moreover, if `t = FunctionInterpolation[InverseFunction[Sin][x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 10]`, and `RegionPlot[t[x] <= y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`, works. I leave the problem for the experts... I am using macOS 10.3 and MMA 11.2

Answer (score 1):

Turning [great comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79572/regionplot-returning-a-number#comment314536_79572) into an answer.

It is a bug (I tested on V11.1) and can be worked around by using `Plot` instead. For completeness I also demonstrate, how to get the edge back:

```
s = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];
g = Plot[{InverseFunction[s][x], x}, {x, -1, 1}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Lighter@Blue, None}}}, PlotStyle -> None];
gc = Cases[g[[1]], _GraphicsComplex];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
  gc /. EdgeForm[___] :> EdgeForm[Black]}, Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]